# php Variable name must change in for loop

Tags: php

On my form I've got a select from a table.  I've put it in a for loop so that each time the name of the select changes to option0, option1, etc.  Then on the action page of the form I need to get the info for each option selected, eg $_POST['option0'], $_POST['option1'], etc to input it into a table.  I can't get the action page to work, what am I doing wrong?

**PAGE1**

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x++) { 
    $get2a = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");
    $opt = "<select name='interviewer". $x . "'>";
    while($row2a = mysqli_fetch_array($get2a)) {
        $intvID = $row2a['intvID'];
        $opt .= "<option value = '";
        $opt .= $row2a['intvID'];
        $opt .= "'>";
        $opt .= $row2a['intvID'];
        $opt .= "</option>";
    }
```

**PAGE 2**

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= 14; $y++) {
    echo $_POST['interviewer . $y . '];
}
```

Comment: it would help if you posted the generated html. I doubt you're generating something that would fit into $_POST['interviewer . $y . '];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your selectable options sets `$opt = "<select name='option". $x . "'>";`

So Page2 should be looking for things names 'option0' ... 'option13'` like this

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= 14; $y++) {
    echo $_POST['option' . $y];    <-- notice slight syntax change also
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I changed it, thank you it is working now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing the post array? Use print_r:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I don't believe the post has something that is named 'interviewer .... something.

besides, if you wish to mix text and variables, use

```
$_POST["interviewer {$x}"]
```

remove the single quotes and the dots. Single quotes do not evaluate variables:

```
$_POST['interviewer . $y . ']; -> wrong
```